# Setting up Hololens MRTK 2.0 with Vuforia in Unity 2019.1

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, hololens, mrtk

I'm developing a Unity app for the Hololens 1 that uses Vuforia. Unfortunately, I cannot get the camera to work with Vuforia, it remains frozen in place and does not follow head movement. When I disable Vuforia, the camera tracks fine.

My setup is as follows:
* Windows 10
* Unity 2019.1.4f1
* MRTK v2.0.0 RC2
* Vuforia 8.1.11

I tried following the steps outlined here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/1461#issuecomment-373714387

To no avail. I also tried having both cameras active, same result. The Vuforia Hololens sample that can be found in the Unity asset store is severely outdated (using the old Holotoolkit, not MRTK), so it is not very useful to me. I noticed that older versions of Vuforia allow the script on the camera to be set to "world center": "camera", but this option is now forced to "device" when Vuforia is configured for the hololens.

Can anyone tell me how to properly configure my scene for MRTK 2 and Vuforia? I'd be eternally grateful for a link to an up to date example project.

**EDIT:**
This seems to be an issue only when using Unity's holographic remote. I would still very much like to resolve that though, since deploying is very time-consuming and makes debugging almost impossible.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:
Import MRTK package and add it to the scene. This will create a MainCamera under MixedRealityPlayspace Game Object.
Then GameObject > VuforiaEngine > ARCamera. This will create an ARCamera with two components: Vuforia Behavior and Default Initialization Error Handler. Copy these two components and add them to the MainCamera created when you added MRTK.
Finally delete ARCamera.
I use Windows 10, Unity 2018.4, MRTKv2.0 and Vuforia 8.
Good luck.

Comment: Doesn't work for me in holographic remote - as soon as any part of Vuforia is in the scene (even just an image target script), the camera is frozen in place. Will check if this still persists in the actual build.

Comment: Seems to work when I compile and deploy the project to the hololens. Apparently it only doesn't work with the holographic remote, which is a shame - having to compile and deploy for every single test is very time-consuming.

Comment: @MiriamTschanen did you make sure the MR camera is present and tagged as MainCamera? Usually when having two cameras Vuforia's ARCamera is always static and doesn't move but this shouldn't matter actually

Comment: @derHugo The answer I replied to specifically recommends deleting the ARCamera after copying its components to the MR camera, which is tagged as MainCamera by default when you create it. I didn't try having two cameras in my scene.

Comment: @MiriamTschanen oh that's true ^^

Comment: Has anybody tried to get this running with the latest release of MRTK (RC2.1)? I've been trying for several hours now to get this working, however, without success. I'm using MRTK RC2.1, Unity 2019.1.9f1, and Vuforia Engine 8.3.8. Everything builds fine without any error messages, but the app crashes as soon as I deploy it on the HoloLens.