# Vuforia image-target crashing Hololens MRTK

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, hololens, mrtk

I'm using vuforia to create a 3D popup/interactable gameobject using Unity 2019.2.8f1 for the Hololens 1 (MRTK package: Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Unity.Foundation.2.2.0). I am trying to get a slider (from MRTK) to popup when the hololens looks at a QR code in the real world. I've followed the instructions/guidance as per: [Setting up Hololens MRTK 2.0 with Vuforia in Unity 2019.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56557121/setting-up-hololens-mrtk-2-0-with-vuforia-in-unity-2019-1) & https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MtiUx_szKbI&t=716s. When simulating the application in Unity, i.e. hitting the play button, the application works fine (it's slightly jittery - but that's just vuforia). When I build and deploy to the Hololens however, I get a `kernelbase.pdb not loaded` error.

More specifically, the error is as follows:

> Exception thrown at 0x76FC3072 in ArmillarySphere.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Platform::AccessDeniedException ^ at memory location 0x15DFFAF0. HRESULT:0x80070005 Access is denied.
>   WinRT information: A network capability is required to access this network resource

This is perplexing as I'm deploying my application to the Hololens via a USB cable - and this method of deployment works for everything until I start to incorporate vuforia.

Has anyone got any idea why this exception is being thrown (or at least point me in the right direction)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think "A network capability is required to access this network resource" has to do with your code, not the way you are deploying your code. Can you elucidate us about any ways your program interacts with networks or the internet?

Comment: That's the thing, it doesn't. Everything should be loaded into the build and the app itself is self contained. It works fine on the simulator (when you hit the play button in unity) using a webcam.